# Cannot select columns in advanced ::with() statement

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a problem selecting columns (MySQL SELECT statement) with an advanced [`query::with`](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading) statement.

```
Property::where('public_id', $publicId)->with(['owner' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('email'));
}])->first();
```

The returned **owner** object is *null* if I add the `select` statement, and the full `User` model if I don't add a `select('...')` statement.

The queries executed are correct and return the desired data if I run them from phpMyAdmin:

```
select * from `properties` where `public_id` = '53f1c59cefe65' limit 1;
select `email` from `users` where `users`.`id` in ('54');
```

Data without select:

```
{"id":4,"owner_id":54,"owner":{"id":54,"username":"ckertzmann","email":"ckertzmann@gmail.com","permissions":[],"activated":true,"activated_at":null,"last_login":null,"first_name":"Daisy","last_name":"Haag","created_at":"2014-08-18 09:21:26","updated_at":"2014-08-18 09:21:26"}}
```

Data with select:

```
{"id":4,"owner_id":54,"owner":null}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the keys so Eloquent knows how to match related models to their respective relation parents.

```
Property::where('public_id', $publicId)->with(['owner' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('email', 'owner_id');
}])->first();
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I just want to clarify that instead of _owner_id_ I used _id_, because that was the column being referenced in the Users table.